# How to update Facebook Profile without announcing it to everyone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

How do I update my profile Basic Info, such as location, education, job, etc. without triggering a notification on Friends' Notification (upper left) or their Wall/Timeline/Recent Friend Activity page. I notice things like "User X has posted/updated their profile for the first time in a while", which I DO NOT want. I DO want friends who visit my actual page to see the the new info, also without any indication that this has been updated (as in recently, I guess).

**Question:** If I set Basic Info privacy levels to "Only Me", update the Basic Info, wait 24 hours (why? because things take time), then switch the privacy level back to "Friends Only". Will this accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Click the update info button of whatever information you wish to update and hit edit.
2. **Click the privacy setting button next to the specific item you will change, and then change the setting to “Only Me.”**
3. Enter your new information, and then save it. Because you set the privacy setting to "Only Me" no one will see the information on their feed but can't see it on your timeline either.
4. Click the **Activity Log** button near the top of your timeline
5. Click the pencil button next to whatever update you just made and select **"Hidden from Timeline"**
6. Return to your timeline and go back to the update info section and whatever new information you just updated, and **change it's privacy setting back to it's original state**. Because you have hidden the update on your own timeline, the update won't appear in your friends timeline either, but if they very specifically click on your page they will see the updated information.

Waiting 24 hours does nothing other than moving that information further down peoples timelines and notifications. This method will make sure that it never appears on their timelines in the first place.

Comment: Like this. Tested? Waiting for an upvote to confirm before marking as answer.

Comment: Tested on my own facebook, also just after you update the information and set it to private it will ask you whether you want to share on your news feed, hit No.

Comment: _Click the pencil button next to whatever update you just made and select "Hidden from Timeline"_, no need to do this if you have already set privacy on your activity log as only me.

Comment: Even hiding from own Timeline is not required once you have set audience as Only Me. Changing audience later doesn't put it n friend's Timeline.

Comment: I marked this as the answer. Sorry it took a while. One last question: So only posts that are marked as viewable by people other than 'only me' at the time of the post will send notifications to friends that you have a new post? I'm asking to make sure because I am also asking for when other people post on my page/wall/timeline (not even sure I know the difference between all of these anymore), I want to be able to control this and make it unannounced __forever__, but made viewable to others later. Obviously, in this case I will choose not to remove it from the timeline/page/wall.

Comment: Yep, sounds right

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will accomplish what you are looking.

If you don't want show changes to your friends, just set the privacy setting to "Only Me" before updating any information. Once you set the "Only Me", no one will able to see your information changes. Later you can set your privacy setting from "Only Me" to any other audience.